# Drop duplicates of permuted multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, multi-index

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
           Correlations       adf
FITB RF        0.984395 -5.484766
WAT  SWK       0.981778 -5.465284
SWK  WAT       0.981778 -5.420976
RF   FITB      0.984395 -5.175268
MCO  BK        0.973801 -4.919812
```

and I want to filter through the indices such that the dataframe drops any repeated values, even if they are permuted. Therefore, the above dataframe would become

```
           Correlations       adf
FITB RF        0.984395 -5.484766
WAT  SWK       0.981778 -5.465284
MCO  BK        0.973801 -4.919812
```

I can't find an efficient means of doing this for a large dataframe. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage `np.sort` + `pd.DataFrame.duplicated`:

```
m = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.index.tolist(), axis=1)).duplicated()
df[~(m.values)]

          Correlations       adf
FITB RF       0.984395 -5.484766
WAT  SWK      0.981778 -5.465284
MCO  BK       0.973801 -4.919812
```

Or, in a similar fashion, using `pd.MultiIndex.duplicated`:

```
m = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [tuple(x) for x in np.sort(df.index.tolist(), axis=1)]
).duplicated()
df[~m]


          Correlations       adf
FITB RF       0.984395 -5.484766
WAT  SWK      0.981778 -5.465284
MCO  BK       0.973801 -4.919812
```

Answer (score 2):

You can using `sorted` + `duplicated`

```
df[~pd.DataFrame(list(map(sorted,df.index.values))).duplicated().values]
          Correlations       adf
FITB RF       0.984395 -5.484766
WAT  SWK      0.981778 -5.465284
MCO  BK       0.973801 -4.919812
```

Answer (score 1):

Index can be normalized with the following function:

```
def normalizeIndex(x):
    splittedString = list(filter(None, x.split(" ")))#split the input string into token with blank space separator and remove empty results
    splittedString.sort()#sort the token list
    return " ".join(splittedString) #return normalized string concatenating ordered token list
```

the function can be applied to index before grouping df on index and selecting the first occurence (anyhow further grouping options can be applied):

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Correlations': [0.984395, 0.981778,0.981778,0.984395,0.973801,],
                   'adf':[-5.484766,-5.465284,-5.420976,-5.175268,-4.919812]},

                  index=['FITB RF','WAT  SWK','SWK  WAT','RF   FITB','MCO  BK',])

    df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: normalizeIndex(x)) #Apply reordering function to df index
    df = df.groupby(df.index).first() #Group the resulting dataframe, by index and, take the first occurence
    print(df)
```

out:

```
         Correlations       adf
BK MCO       0.973801 -4.919812
FITB RF      0.984395 -5.484766
SWK WAT      0.981778 -5.465284
```